# how to get the fingerprint from the keytool command?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, keytool

I am having trouble getting the keytool command to work.

```
C:\Users\Psiu>$keytool - list - alias androiddebugkey - keystore C:\Users\Psiu\.android\debug.keystore 
-storepass android -keypass android
```

When I run the command, I get the following message.

'$keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Any advice?

Comment: The $ is just the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

remove the $ that is just a part of linux command prompt

EDIT: 
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Psiu.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: i have tried removing the $ sign and im still getting the same error

Comment: remove the white spaces after each -

Comment: Do you have the bin folder of java in your path?

Comment: Then windows can not find the command keytool. move to the bin folder in your jre installation. Mine is located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin" and verify that keytool.exe is there then run keytool from there

Comment: now ive changed the path name to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" still doesnt work

Comment: is there a dot before keytool, then remove it?

Comment: theres no dot before keytool

Comment: if you go into that folder. Do not use path cd to the folder end then write keytool. Do you get a long list of possible switches?

Comment: what do you mean? i dont understand

Comment: first cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\" and then just write keytool there do you get a list or an error message?

Comment: i managed to get the certificate fingerprint but when i enter it into the google maps site to generate the API key, it says the fingerprint is invalid

Comment: Then that is another question. Mark this as answered and create another one.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the steps through the Command Prompt that worked for me :

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin keytool -list -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\ {username}.android\debug.keystore
>   -storepass android -keypass android